# .append method is replacing value

Tags: python

I am trying to create an array of rmse values by looping a method that generates each one one by one... I can see why the value appended ends up replacing the entire array. I am however, unsure as to how i could change it to make it work...

This is the code:

```
preds = np.asarray(prediction_Arr)
GSPC = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', 
    start=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 
    end=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31))
real = np.asarray(GSPC['Close'][0:])
rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((real - preds),2)))
print(rmse)
rmse_values.append(rmse)
print(rmse_values)
```

This is the Minimal, Complete Verifiable as requested:

```
b = []
x = 1
for f in range(0,3):
    x = x + 1
    print(x)

b.append(x)
```

if I do "print(b)"
I get [4]

but i want to see [2,3,4], I would like the array to contain all of the values x has within the range.

Hope this is clear

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This looks like the inside of a loop. Are you initiating a list called rmse_values outside of the loop?

Comment: Why would you expect to have more than one value appended when the `append` is outside of the loop? Your original question didn't show a loop so it was impossible to know what your problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `rmse_values` is defined within the scope of your loop, so it's not replacing the values but it's redefined in each iteration.

You need to define it outside the loop, using your code (with some assumptions) it would be something like this:

```
rmse_values = []
for prediction_Arr in prediction_Arrs:
  preds = np.asarray(prediction_Arr)
  GSPC = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', 
      start=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1), 
      end=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31))
  real = np.asarray(GSPC['Close'][0:])
  rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((real - preds),2)))
  print(rmse)
  rmse_values.append(rmse)

print(rmse_values)
```

Comment: note that if you are not appending inside the loop you will append the last `prediction_Arr` into `rmse_values`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't appending inside the loop

```
b = []
x = 1
for f in range(0,3):
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
    b.append(x) #this needs to be inside the loop. 
print b
```